# Explain $\tan^2(\tan^{-1}(x))$ becoming $x^2$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

How does $\tan^2(\tan^{-1}(x))$ become $x^2$?

---

I feel that the answer should contain a tan somewhere and not just simply $x^2$. "Why?" you might ask, well I thought that $\tan^2(\theta)$ was a special function that has to be rewritten a specific way.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I really don't feel that this question needs a context though. The answer provided by GenericNickname is a perfect answer to the question. I'll edit the question but it will not make it better in *my* opinion.

Comment: I think the crucial bias is explained by "*which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it*". It is unclear what prevented you from a straight-forward application of the definition.

Comment: Rewrite as $(\tan(\tan^{-1}(x))^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition $\tan(\tan^{-1}(x)) = x$ because $\tan^{-1}(x)$ does **not** mean $1/\tan(x)$ but the inverse function to $\tan(x)$.

Another convention is that $(\tan(x))^2$ is too long for some people and they will just write $\tan^2(x)$.

Putting these two things together, you get

$$\tan^2(\tan^{-1}(x)) = (\tan(\tan^{-1}(x)))^2 = (x)^2 = x^2$$

Comment: You are referring to fleeting conventions as "definitions" which is only underscored by inconsistent interpretation of $f^{k}$.

Comment: @A.S. Please don't regard this question as ill willed but what are commonly accepted 'definitions' if not widely spread conventions? I doubt that more than a handful mathematicians would not identify $f^{-1}$ as the inverse function of $f$. On the other hand, using $f^k$ for $k > 1$ really is a 'convention' since depending of the mathematical area people interpret it differently (in this case, $k$-power vs. composition vs. $k$-derivative)

Comment: To me, there's a qualitative difference between a definition of an object ("inverse of a function is"), and notation for such an object ("denote the inverse by $f^{-1}$"). The former is more descriptive than the latter and is subject to less confusion/context-dependency. I certainly agree that $\tan^{-1}$ is more commonly used to denote $\arctan$ rather than $\frac 1 {\tan}$ but I'm quite sure that, absent some context, both identifications could be present (possibly differing between countries, textbooks, etc.). Also note that $x^{-1}$ means $\frac 1 x$ - and never inverse of $f(x)=id(x)=x$.

Comment: Maybe the matter is that I've finished high-school outside of US and have exclusively used $\arctan$ to refer to inverse $\tan$ and when I started first encountering $\tan^{-1}$ it would cause confusion even though definitions of inverse tangent were the same on both continents. I still have to stop and remind myself of the predominant convention for $\tan^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $\tan^{-1}x $ is *not* the `reciprocal` of $\tan x$, but the inverse function $\arctan x$.

Comment: $\tan^{-1}$ is ambiguous, just as $\tan^2$ is ($\tan\tan$ or $(\tan)^2$) and the usage of powers is clearly inconsistent in the OP.